# Unable to connect to services from node-host

Tags: kubernetes

I'm running `kube-proxy` on each of my kubernetes nodes. I see, that it is installing it's iptables rules, to create virtual services hosts. I use flannel overlay networking to connect together the docker networks of my nodes. This works all fine from inside docker containers. So I am able to connect to the pods directly as well as to the services from inside a docker container.

But due to certain requirements I need to access services from a node host, in the same way as from inside a docker container. The problem is, that this is just possible for the node, a service pod is running on.

See the following example of `iptables-save` on an node, that is not hosting a kubernetes-dashboard pod as clarification (the pod is running on kube-node-2):

```
[root@kube-node-1 ~]# iptables-save | grep dashboard
-A KUBE-SEP-CAT6SKLXJIMXS63T -s 172.16.99.5/32 -m comment --comment    "kube-system/kubernetes-dashboard:" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-CAT6SKLXJIMXS63T -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube- system/kubernetes-dashboard:" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination  172.16.99.5:9090
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.254.242.220/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kubernetes-dashboard: cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 80 -j KUBE-SVC-XGLOHA7QRQ3V22RZ
-A KUBE-SVC-XGLOHA7QRQ3V22RZ -m comment --comment "kube-system/kubernetes-dashboard:" -j KUBE-SEP-CAT6SKLXJIMXS63T
```

I'm now able to `curl http://172.16.99.5:9090` but I'm not able to `curl http://10.254.242.220` (on kube-node-2 this command succeeds). On the other hand, from the same host a `docker run -it --rm centos /usr/bin/curl http://10.254.242.220` does work.

I have the intuition, that something with the iptables rules and NATing is missing, such that, all packages jump into the `KUBE-SERVICES` chain. Perhaps somebody can help me understanding, what's going on and provide a solution.

Comment: What Flannel backend are you using? Could it be that the destination host is blocking traffic originating from the source host's IP using a firewall?

Comment: I want to use VXLAN backend.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access services from outside the kubernetes cluster, you need to use service type `NodePort`, see http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#publishing-services---service-types.
If you want to use ports outside of the default port range (30000-32767), you can additionally allow a new range with the `--service-node-port-range` option of the api server, see http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kube-apiserver/.

Greetings, Marc

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm well aware of the official documented methods to publish services. But unfortunately this is not, what I want for development. There I want to develop one service in isolation on my development machine. This service should have access to the cluster services, as it was running inside.

Comment: ok, I understand. Then just probably need to add a route. I'm not an expert with this topic, but we did sth like that for accessing pods in a AWS hosted cluster from our local development machines. Should work for services too:
`sudo route -n add -net <SERVICE_IP_RANGE> <K8S_MASTER_IP>`

Comment: Did you try this? I was not able with just a route, as there is a lot of NAT and address rewriting.

Comment: We still use this (automated, routes are added by OpenVPN when we connect to the AWS network). It's probably not the same setup as yours, but I hoped it would help...